# Como remover foco do botão após o clique

Tags: javascript

**Como remover o foco do botão depois que ele for clicado**

> Tenho essa função que adiciona um evento quando um botão é clicado.

```
    e.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        updatedCount(event.target.dataset.button);
        resetCount(event.target.dataset.button);
    })
})
```

> Essa função adiciona um evento quando uma tecla é pressionada.

```
    if (event.code === "Enter") {
        count += 1;
    }
    else if (event.code === "Backspace") {
        (count <= 0) ? count = 0 : count += - 1;
    }
    text.textContent = count;
    localStorage.setItem("key", count);
})
```

> Eu preciso que o evento ocorra quando um botão é clicado ou quando uma tecla é pressionada, porém se a tecla for pressionada depois de um botão ser clicado cria-se um conflito, pois o foco está no botão clicado. Como tirar o foco do botão?

Comment: *"Como remover o foco do botão depois que ele for clicado"*,  já tentou usar o evento "mouseup"?

Answer (score -3):

Tenta usar o método .blur no elemento após o evento de. click que aí o evento vai tirar o foco do botão, logo se uma tecla for pressionada o conflito não acontecerá.

Comment: Eu tentei mas não deu certo, não sei se seria o caso. Eu teria como associar um evento keyup ao evento de click? Por exemplo, ao clicar em certa tecla, certo botão será ativado